# icon in ttf android studio

Tags: java, icons, truetype, weather

I want a .ttf file to icon. I am referencing the file like (`icon = "& # xf00d;";` ). But it doesn't work. Where could the problem be. Thanks in advance for your help

I'm use https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jaRXMKBg1x-OoSz8hFxpu1ZjhNm6idrd/view?fbclid=IwAR29TZQOjnvfJU7eLyTtXU6n2VY-DN-nnjh1vQpYYXsszaYQ9l7uN4RP9gU these icons

Answer (score 0):

I guess these are the same icons proposed in [weather icons like font awesome](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/) So I recommend to use html  tag to include them. Actually I am not familiar with android studio but I am pretty sure that it has ability to include font icons.